# Hubspot Post Filter module

Tags: hubspot

Hubspot Post Filter module can we change "see all" link to open a new page with all post filters

I dont want bottom see all link to expand instead want it to open a new page with all links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new site page with post filter with (display all posts option set)
2. On you current page with the see all, change the value of the "see all" achor href to point to the site page in one 1);